# Unable to Install Net::SSH::Perl module on Windows 64 bit

Tags: perl, ssh

I am trying to install Net::SSH::Perl module on Windows using CPAN, but it is failing with a windows prompt saying "ar.exe has stopped working".
Attached screenshot.
Can somebody please help.

[image: Error Installing Net SSH Perl on windows]

Comment: Which version of Windows?  What version of Perl?  Is it a distribution like ActiveState or Strawberry?

Comment: Windows 7. Perl 5.22, Active Perl

Comment: The ActivState link for the Net::SSH::Perl module doesn't look good: http://code.activestate.com/ppm/Net-SSH-Perl/ but what happens if you do ppm install Net-SSH-Perl

Comment: D:\Users\sujpadhi\Desktop\Scripts>ppm install Net::SSH::Perl
Downloading ActiveState Package Repository dbimage...done
Syncing site PPM database with .packlists...done
Syncing perl PPM database with .packlists...done
No missing packages to install